# I need to develop a common push notification server using java web technologies

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I need to develop a common push notification server using java web technology  for mobile devices(android,ios and windows phone,etc.. ).i mean that i need to push notifications to mobile devices from this server ,how it is possible ? i need some ideas ..so please help to accomplish this task...

Thank you .

Comment: Are you applications native apps or mobile web apps?

Answer (score 1):

Push notifications can be done using Comet servlets or smth like that. 
I've used XMPP (Chat system) for such tasks. 
So your server and clients communicate through chat system (Openfire).
Looks like this:
CLIENT APP---->OPENFIRE<-----SERVER APP

Your server sends message to client and on client side you handle that message and make some actions!

Comment: i have stuck in similar kind of situation. What plugin have you used in Openfire server and how did you access it from your iOS application?

Comment: @ArunKumarMunusamy i didn't accessed it from iOS (it was 2012 - iPhones didn't exists at that times :)

Comment: No problem. Thank you. But.. FYI, first iphone was launched on June 29, 2007.. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about [pusher](http://pusher.com) ? I've used this service with [java-libpusher](https://github.com/capotej/java-libpusher) and it seemed quite straightforward. Also check [publisher libraries](http://pusher.com/docs/rest_libraries#java)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have push notifications for web/mobile web, you can implement it in Java using [cometd](http://cometd.org/).

If you want to push to Apple or Android devices, following links can get you started:

1. http://blog.serverdensity.com/2010/10/07/android-push-notifications-tutorial/
2. http://blog.serverdensity.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late on this, but Google Cloud Messaging is a good solution for anyone else who might need a push service. You can check it out here : https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: or to answer question https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns

Answer (score -1):

This can be designed in different ways,

1. JMS based, where Event will generate an message and send it mobile. (This is preffered as its event based approach)
2. CRON job based, where job is running and on some condition is generate message to mobile. (This would be continuously running a job)
3. A DB trigger, which checks the DB and same as above point (Not so good as per today's design concepts)

Elaborate more what exactly you need, if this is not answering your issue.

Thanks.